# How to solve this error: “Value error: TiffPage 0: <COMPRESSION.LZW: 5> requires the ‘imagecodecs’ packages”?

Tags: python

I’m working on two tiff files. I run a command (pixel search) using cmd so this error appeared. I installed imagecodecs package but the problem is still not resolved. I worked on tiff files with smaller size, no error appeared.

Comment: Make sure to install `imagecodecs` into the same Python environment that you are using to run your command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.